# Await with and without task assigning

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider a little function:

```
private async Task LittleFunction()
{
  var operand = new SomeObject();
  var notUsedResult =  await SomeAsyncOperationWith(operand); // 1
  // OR
  await SomeAsyncOperationWith(operand); // 2
  SomeOtherOperationsWith(operand); 
}
```

Is there any difference between *1* and *2*? I know about context and other task properties I can use, but now I'm interesting in differences in state machines behavior. Thanks.

Comment: I believe there is no difference.  Both should achieve the same state machine behavior, except that the second discards the result of the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between these two; though if you do not require an assignment, in my opinion it's better to skip it for improved readability (i.e. should the methods have more going on than the simple examples above, by not introducing a new variable then no one needs to mentally keep track of `notUsedResult` (though your naming does a good job of that anyway).

```
// 1
private async Task LittleFunction()
{
  var operand = new SomeObject();
  var notUsedResult =  await SomeAsyncOperationWith(operand); 
  SomeOtherOperationsWith(operand); 
}

// 2
private async Task LittleFunction()
{
  var operand = new SomeObject();
  await SomeAsyncOperationWith(operand); 
  SomeOtherOperationsWith(operand); 
}
```

There is, however, a third option:

```
// 3
private async Task LittleFunction()
{
  var operand = new SomeObject();
  var task = SomeAsyncOperationWith(operand); 
  SomeOtherOperationsWith(operand); 
  await task;
}
```

This is different to the above in that `SomeAsyncOperationWith` is called before `SomeOtherOperationsWith`, but may not complete until afterwards.  This is better if there's no dependency between the two tasks as it allows the function to execute the `SomeOtherOperationsWith` logic whilst it's waiting on any IO / long running operation going on in `SomeAsyncOperationWith` (i.e. this is the benefit of using `async` in the first place).  Of course, if there is a dependency to have the `SomeAsyncOperationWith` task complete before `SomeOtherOperationsWith`, you'll need to stick with one of your original solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and for the third option explanation!

Answer (score 3):

There is no appreciable difference in the 2 methods and if anything they will result in the same IL, however you can prove this for your self with a .net disassembler.

I think the more interesting point of this question is

> but now I'm interesting in differences in state machines behavior.

How the state machine works is an implementation detail and likely to change from version to version (and has changed a lot since `async` was first implemented).

What you should be concerned with is your environment, if you have a performance issue you should use a profiler, or benchmark framework and not second guess the internals of the CLR and Jitter

Comment: I think, *differences in state machines behavior* was a bad expression from my side. I mean not implementation details themselves, but how they are can influence on my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The *implementation* of `SomeAsyncOperationWith(operand);` is responsible for creating a `Task`, scheduling any work which cannot be immediately completed to occur at appropriate times and deciding when to mark the `Task` that it returns as Completed, Cancelled or Faulted.

It neither knows, nor cares, about what any calling method *does* with that returned `Task` nor the `Result` that the `Task` ends up containing.

Nothing about the "state machine" (if such even exists) is exposed to the caller.